# elapsed time from the time of opening of a container

Tags: physical

Does anybody know of any packaging which measures elapsed time from the time of opening? I have conducted a great deal of research and have found packaging which monitors exposure to temprature and changes in temprature, light, humidity, etc. but not elapsed time. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to ask this at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: meir: What kind of items or subtance do you want to store inside that packaging? How big does it have to be, how hard to destroy, how airproof, how waterproof, etc.? What kind of environment will the package be stored in? Does it have to be legitimately opened at any time? How resistant to the countermeasures have to be to a determined attacker (e.g. equipped with the right chemicals, if the item is put in a freezer, …)? And what does this have to do with wifi? @F.Hauri What on earth does this question have to do with server administration?

Comment: When in doubt, C4. A time-delay fuse is an easiest option.

Comment: TIMEbadge makes self-expiring labels that chemically change to reveal "expired" after a certain amount of time (day, week, month).  Perhaps they can custom manufacture a solution to solve your problem. Be prepared to spend money.  See http://timebadge.com.au/tokens.htm . If it's really expensive cargo, some kind of GPS/GSM tracker might be called for.

Comment: @Gilles, As this seem to be a question about monitoring, and monitoring is more relevant on ServerFault (1523/156,224=>0.97%) than SO (1433/5,629,095=>0.03%). On other way, the question stand for *container*, mostly used to split/share server ressources.

Comment: @meir: `uptime` ??